# How to drag a modal window's parent window

Tags: javascript, electron

so In electron i have a parent window, and on a ipc event it opens up a child window, how would i open up the child window (which is set to a modal window) but still be able to drag the parent window? so i want the parent window of the child modal window, to still be able to be dragged even though the child window is a modal one

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')

let win;
let taskWin;

function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        height: 800,
        width: 1300,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
        }

    })
    win.webContents.openDevTools()

    win.loadFile('index.html')
    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null
    })


}

ipcMain.on('createTask', () => {
    taskWin = new BrowserWindow({

        height: 600,
        width: 1000,
        parent: win,
        modal: true,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
        }
    })
    taskWin.loadFile('createtask.html')
    taskWin.on('closed', () => {
        taskWin = null
    })

})

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```